# extracting string from json in ruby and js

Tags: javascript, ruby, json, elixir, ecto

Currently, we are using an Elixir API for our project build in ruby. and As we are using Ecto validation for validating our params. there is a traversing function through which we can get the error but it came in as

```
  "message": {
    "to_date": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "title": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "requested_by": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "from_date": [
      "can't be blank"
    ],
    "exid": [
      "can't be blank"
    ]
  }
}
```

is there any way to extract these messages in a good form? such as they should be represented as `exid can't be black`

Comment: Where do you have the params?  Are they in your JS or your Ruby or your Elixer?

Comment: params are being sent through both JS AJAX and also in a ruby wrapper as well. That's why am asking for both solutions. Elixir endpoints are just returning messages / data. in the case of messages, they look like the above case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're looking for. Maybe something like this?

```
function sanitizeErrors(errs) {
  var msg = errs.message;
  var result = {};

  for (var key in msg) {
    result[key] = key.replace('_', ' ') + ' ' + msg[key][0];
  }

  return result;
}
```

You can test it out here: http://jsbin.com/saviyi/edit?js,console

It produces an object that looks like this:

```
{
  exid: "exid can't be blank",
  from_date: "from date can't be blank",
  requested_by: "requested by can't be blank",
  title: "title can't be blank",
  to_date: "to date can't be blank"
}
```

Comment: thats pretty much awesome!

Comment: but in any case, can't we have such as 
`{message: "exit can't is blank."}` or in any chance, we can get the first one only?

Comment: It is returning the first error per field. Do you mean, you want to discard all field errors except for the first one? (e.g. Just get `{message: 'exid can't be blank'}). You can do that, for sure, but generally, you want to show each field that has an error.

Answer (score 0):

Using your browsers built in JSON parser, if it has javascript support, you can `JSON.parse` with your message as an argument and then do one of these four things off the top of my head.

- access it in on same line.
- put it into another javascript object.
- return it to your caller.
- iterate over it.

You can access it then with any iterators, or with dot notation like

```
b=JSON.parse('{"a":"b","7":0,"1":0,"0":1,"5":[1,5,8,6],"g":"Hello World"}').a
#The string "b"
b[7] # 0
b[5] # an array with 1 5 8 and 6
alert(b.g)
```

Try it in your browsers console!!

The square brackets mean you get each message as the first element in an array, but that is super easy to deal with!